# How to implement manual ordering with PouchDB / CouchDB

Tags: nosql, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm building an app and looking to use PouchDB / CouchDB to implement a syncing database.

My question is what's the best practice for storing a manual sort order for each item in the database, and being able to update a large number of items when their sort order needs to change?

My use case is a simple drag and drop interface where users can organise long lists of items. These lists could potentially include hundreds of items.

With MySQL, I know I can simply do something like this after moving an item:

`Update my_table SET sort_order = sort_order + 1 WHERE sort_order >= {sort_order of moved item};`

However, I don't think it's possible to write such a straight forward bulk query with CouchDB. Are there any recommendations or best practice for handling this situation? Thanks!

Comment: You create a view, or a Mango query, which sorts on your `sort_order` field.

Comment: What about bulk updating items when I want to reorder something? If there are 1000 database entries is it easy to increment them all in one go as per the MySQL query above?

Comment: Use the `_bulk_docs` endpoint for bulk updates. It's not "easy", though... you still have to update the entire doc, as always, in *ouchDB